# How to deserialize Firestore document with its id using json_serializable in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple Message document in my Firestore database that has some fields.

[image]

I use `json_serializable` to deserialize it to object. My class looks like follows:

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'message_firestore.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable(nullable: true, explicitToJson: true)
class MessageFirestore extends Equatable {
  MessageFirestore(
      this.id, this.content, this.conversationId, this.senderId, this.dateSent);

  factory MessageFirestore.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$MessageFirestoreFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$MessageFirestoreToJson(this);

  @JsonKey(name: 'Id')
  final String id;
  @JsonKey(name: 'Content')
  final String content;
  @JsonKey(name: 'ConversationId')
  final String conversationId;
  @JsonKey(name: 'SenderId')
  final String senderId;
  @JsonKey(name: 'DateSent', fromJson: _fromJson, toJson: _toJson)
  final DateTime dateSent;

  static DateTime _fromJson(Timestamp val) =>
      DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(val.millisecondsSinceEpoch);
  static Timestamp _toJson(DateTime time) =>
      Timestamp.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(time.millisecondsSinceEpoch);
}
```

There is no field called `Id` in the document, so currently its id is not being deserialized. 
<s>However, the `key` of the map retrieved from Firestore is its id, so this value can be read by manually deserializing the map.</s>
I wish to have access to the id of the document (_b03002...) during deserialization.

Is there any way to configure `json_serializable` to read this id and store it in `id` property?

Comment: > However, the key of the map retrieved from Firestore is its id....

what `key` are you talking about? A Map has many keys.

Comment: What I meant by _`key` of the map_ was `b0300...` id on the screenshot. I found that it's available in `DocumentSnapshot` as property `documentID`. I wish I could have access to this id while deserializing the object. I'll try to clarify this in my question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could modify the `fromJson` constructor, so that you'd provide the id on the first parameter.

```dart
factory MessageFirestore.fromJson(String id, Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return _$MessageFirestoreFromJson(json)..id = id;
}
```

Then, from your caller, it'll be something like this

```dart
Message(snapshot.documentID, snapshot.data)
```

Comment: Hi, what is that .. called?

Comment: That's the [cascade notation](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#cascade-notation-)

Comment: Thank you Yaobin

Comment: @YaobinThen Is it possible to do this in the( context of json_serializable) if the class is a property of Message?

Comment: Not sure if I understood this correctly, class is a property of message? Perhaps you want to encapsulate the passing of `documentID` inside the Message class?

`factory Message.fromDocumentSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) =>
      _$MessageFromJson(snapshot.data)..id = snapshot.documentID;`

Comment: What about `toJson`? Would need to remove the `id` somehow, right?

Comment: That depends on whether do you want to include `id` in your JSON.

Comment: You will also need to change your `final String id` to `String? id` or at least `late String id` and then remove it from your constructor. Otherwise you might end up with a null error when loading your Message from Firebase

Comment: as of Freezed v2.2.0 this no longer works when you use a freezed model class as a field inside another model class and you get an error from the code generator:
```
Expecting a `fromJson` constructor with exactly one positional parameter. The only extra parameters allowed are functions of the form `T Function(Object?) fromJsonT` where `T` is a type parameter of the target type.
```

Comment: Actually the above comment is not quite correct, this seems to actually due to json_serialisable so as of json_serialisable v6.5.4 the above error occurs. Likely from this: https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart/issues/1017 and related to: https://github.com/google/json_serializable.dart/issues/870

Answer (score 3):

You could add another factory into MessageFirestore class.

```
  factory MessageFirestore.fromFire(DocumentSnapshot doc) =>
      _$MessageFirestoreFromFire(doc);
```

after that you will have two factory function in you class.

```
factory MessageFirestore.fromFire(DocumentSnapshot doc) //...

factory MessageFirestore.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) //...
```

and add `_$MessageFirestoreFromFire(doc)` function with copying `_$MessageFirestoreFromJson(json)` function into `message_firestore.g.dart` file and edit it like this:

```
MessageFirestore _$MessageFirestoreFromFire(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
  return MessageFirestore(
    id: doc.documentID,
    content: doc.data['name'] as String,
    // ... other parameters 
  );
}
```

and in you service to reading the documents you can:

```
  Stream<List<MessageFirestore>> getMessageList() {
    return Firestore.instance
        .collection('YourCollectionPath')
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapShot) => snapShot.documents
            .map(
              (document) => MessageFirestore.fromFire(document),
            )
            .toList());
  }
```

Easy Peasy

And also this method doesn't interference with other classes that use MessageFirestore instance.

Have a nice day and wish this method works for you. :)

Answer (score 2):

Improvement to [Yaobin Then](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59639340/5727960)'s post: Also remove id on `toJson`:

```
factory MessageFirestore.fromJson(String id, Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return _$MessageFirestoreFromJson(json)..id = id;
}

Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
  var json = _$MessageFirestoreToJson(this);
  json.removeWhere((key, value) => key == 'id');
  return json;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using  [Yaobin Then](https://stackoverflow.com/users/410487/yaobin-then)'s answer, we can improve it forward like this:

```dart
factory MessageFirestore.fromJson(String id, Map<String, dynamic> json) {
  return _$MessageFirestoreFromJson(json)..id = id;
}

factory MessageFirestore.fromFire(QueryDocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
  return MessageFirestore.fromJson(snapshot.id, snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);
}
```

Then, from your caller, it'll be something like this

```dart
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: ...,
  builder: (context, snp) {
    final products = snp.data?.docs;

    if (products?.isNotEmpty != true) {
      return const Center(
        child: Text('No products'),
      );
    }

    final prods = products!.map(
      (prod) {
        return MessageFirestore.fromFire(prod);
      },
    ).toList();
```

this way you do not have to fill the 2 arguments in every call, the `fromFire` factory will handle it for you

Comment: By setting the id after it has been deserialized requires the object to be mutable, most often not desired.

Comment: @TomTom101 for immutable objects we can do something like `factory MessageFirestore.fromJson(String id, Map<String, dynamic> json) { return MessageFirestoreFromJson(json).copyWith(id: id); }`

Comment: Then json_serializable complains about "exactly one positional argument expected" or similar.

Comment: @TomTom101 can you try this https://gist.github.com/adnanjpg/80cc0892b10bf1f1a14b53d20b8d6ad7?

Comment: I should switch to Freezed, I guess. This looks fine, a minor thing here is that the object is generated twice

Comment: Well, double creating the object is a small price we have to pay. to solve this we would have to either write the json deserialization ourselves, which is not a good thing, or what I do is to just store the id in the document, so when I fetch the data I already would have the id in the snapshot.data().